# socat getaddrinfo() "temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: linux, tcp, vpn, ipv6, socat

## Hi there,

I am currently trying to set up an "ipv4" TCP-VPN-connection to my DS-Lite attached home-network.
For this purpose I have an external root server with both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.
The server will pull the latest DNS entry made by my home-server (`vpn6.server.me`) and start forwarding the v4 Port to the resolved v6 Port using `socat`. This is working fine so far.

shortened script:

```
# local forward port to bind
loport=8443

# remote host to forward to
# this has to be a ipv6 AAAA dns record
myhost=vpn6.server.me
myport=8443

myipv6=$(getent hosts $myhost | awk '{ print $1 }' | head -n 1)

screen -dmSL ipv6proxy socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:$loport,fork TCP6:​[$myipv6]:$myport
```

I have taken the necessary steps at the home-router to allow ipv6-traffic coming in on the given port.

I have also confirmed that the resolved address `$myipv6` is correct and ping-able from the server:

```
> ping6 vpn6.server.me
PING vpn6.server.me(2a02:908:2212:XXXX:ba27:XXXX:XXXX:116c) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a02:908:2212:XXXX:ba27:XXXX:XXXX:116c: icmp_seq=1 ttl=245 time=41.2 ms
64 bytes from 2a02:908:2212:XXXX:ba27:XXXX:XXXX:116c: icmp_seq=2 ttl=245 time=38.3 ms
64 bytes from 2a02:908:2212:XXXX:ba27:XXXX:XXXX:116c: icmp_seq=3 ttl=245 time=26.5 ms
```

## On to the problem

when trying to establish a connection, the vpn will load for a while and fail with `TCP recv EOF`.

In the socat-screen the following error prints:

`2019/12/28 21:00:56 socat[3569] E getaddrinfo("​[2a02:908:2212:XXXX:ba27:XXXX:XXXX:116c]", "NULL", {1,10,1,6}, {}): Temporary failure in name resolution`

**And I really can't figure out why that is.**

Several different resolve methods always returned the correct ipv6 and I'm able to ping it.

I've already tried to reboot the server without any success.

Perhaps I missed something, but this error doesnt really make much sense to me in the first place because IPv6 addresses dont need to be resolved.. so maybe there is a way to **disable this "resolving" specifically for socat** which fails?

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: I think it's the [brackets] sounds the IPv6 address. Those shouldn't be  included when specifying the address. That's only valid in URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea, but when run without brackets, `socat` will think the ipv6 is wrongly formatted:
`TCP6: wrong number of parameters (9 instead of 2)`

Comment: Right, the brackets are ok. The only strange thing I can see is that you have a space after `TCP6:`. Is that a copy&paste error in your question? I just ran `socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:10000,fork TCP6:[2a06:efc0:3::253:0]:80` and it works fine.